# How do I correctly freeze time w/ Timecop in my spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I am trying to use a combination of Timecop and querying the arel where_sql to data, but I can't seem to get Timecop to actually freeze the time.  I've tried Timecop.freeze and Timecop.freeze(Time.now), both of which are slightly off when using Time.now in my spec.

What am I missing?  Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.1.0.rc5

--

error

```
Failure/Error: Game.unreleased.arel.where_sql.should eq("WHERE (release_date > '#{Time.now}')")


     expected "WHERE (release_date > '0000-01-01 00:00:00 -0500')"
     got "WHERE (release_date > '0000-01-01 05:00:00.000000')"
```

model

```
scope :unreleased, lambda { |limit = 4| where('release_date > ?', Time.now).
                                        order('release_date asc').
                                        limit(limit) }
```

spec

```
it "should retrieve games with a release date later than today" do
  Timecop.freeze
  Game.unreleased.arel.where_sql.should eq("WHERE (release_date > '#{Time.now}')")
end
```

Comment: Looking at this closer, I don't think it's timecop but an issue in timestamp formats.  Now to just figure that piece out.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

My usage of timecop in specs always looks like this:

```
Timecop.travel(Time.zone.local(2010, 6, 1, 13, 0, 0)) do
  .. time sensitive spec here ..
end
```

It's also generally good practice to use the Time.zone proxy (Time.zone.now, Time.zone.utc, Time.zone.local, etc) when dealing with time in a rails app.

Comment: There is still an issue with displaying the correct timestamp format as used in the where clause, but your Timecop answer is correct.

Answer (score 7):

I just had a problem running Timecop with RSpec's `expect` syntax when I was running:

```
it "updates :completed_at" do
  Timecop.freeze
  expect(@task.completed_at).to eq(Time.zone.now)
end
```

Where the times weren't matching. To solve, I put `Timecop.freeze` in a `before` clause.

(I realize this question is older and RSpec's `expect` syntax wasn't around, but I think adding `Timecop.freeze` to a `before` block or clause may help people who have the same problem mentioned in the original question. Certainly, it doesn't seem like asking a new question and answering it is worthwhile since my question would be very very similar to the one above.)

Answer (score 4):

Travel to the date and include TimeHelpers, example:

```
include ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers

let!(:archived_date) { Time.zone.now }

travel_to(archived_date) do
  expect(OrderService.getOrder(some_old_order).archived_at).to eq Time.zone.now
end
```

Comment: You're making a good point, but you're not directly answering the question; therefore, you should have been more explicit: You're *not* using `Timecop` but a Rails Helper Method (`travel_to`) and this method (amongst others) is available as of *Rails 4.1*.

Comment: Ruby on Rails [TimeHelpers documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'timecop'

# freeze time to August 1st 2022 in this block
Timecop.freeze(2022, 8, 1) do
  result = something_that_uses_time()
end
```